# WordPress wp_nav_menu specific sub menu only

Tags: wordpress, menu

I want to create a menu that pulls only the sub-menu options for a particular page.

For example, if the menu option DASHBOARD has the sub-menus MESSAGE BOARD and CALENDAR, I want to be able to create a separate menu with just MESSAGE BOARD and CALENDAR.

I'd like to do this without the wp_list_pages function so that the menu options can be managed using the Appearances > Menus tab in WordPress.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want additional menu items for sub pages?

I.E. You have a menu that looks like this

HOME ABOUT DASHBOARD FAQ CONTACT

DASHBOARD has 2 sub-pages -> BOARD CALENDAR

When you are on the DASHBOARD page you want the BOARD and CALENDAR pagees to show like this:

HOME ABOUT DASHBOAR FAQ CONTACT
           BOARD CALENDAR

You can add an aditional menu in functions.php like this

```
<?php if (function_exists('register_nav_menus'))
{
    register_nav_menus
    (
        array
        (
            'main_nav'=>'main menu', // your main menu
            'dash_nav'=>'dashboard menu', //your dashboard menu

        )
    );
}?>
```

And then create a page template for dashboard which will have this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'dashboard menu'));?>
```

EDIT:

Well you could edit the header.php and add something like this

```
<?php if (is_page_template('dashboard.php') :?>
    <link href="csspath" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php endif;?>
```

That way you add another css file that overrides the submenu.

Comment: In this instance, I'm trying to limit the number of menus I have to register, so I was hoping to get a little more functionality out of an existing menu. Since the structure of the menu already exists as a sub-menu, I'm wondering if there is a way to take advantage of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar desire as you to select and only show a sub menu being just the children menu items from an existing wordpress menu. This can be done by editing the functions.php and adding a shortcode that has it's own walker class to target and display a submenu.

#### PHP code for "menu" shortcode and customized menu walker class (all goes in functions.php):

```
    //register menu shortcode
    add_shortcode('menu', 'shortcode_menu');
    function shortcode_menu($args ) {
            //don't echo the ouput so we can return it
            $args['echo']=false;
            //in case menu isn't found display a message
            $args['fallback_cb']='shortcode_menu_fallback';
            //check if showing a submenu, if so make sure everything is setup to do so
            if (isset($args['show_submenu']) && !empty($args['show_submenu'])) {
                    if (!isset($args['depth'])) {
                            $args['depth']=1;
                    }
                    $args['walker']=new Sub_Menu_Walker_Nav_Menu();
            }
            $menu=wp_nav_menu( $args );
            return $menu;
    }
    //message to display if menu isn't found
    function shortcode_menu_fallback($args ) {return 'No menu selected.';}

    //special walker_nav_menu class to only display submenu
    //depth must be greater than 0
    //show_submenu specifies submenu to display
    class Sub_Menu_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
      if ( !$element )
       return;

      $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

      $displaythiselement=$depth!=0;
      if ($displaythiselement) {
              //display this element
              if ( is_array( $args[0] ) )
               $args[0]['has_children'] = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
              $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
              call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);
      }

      $id = $element->$id_field;
      if ( is_array( $args[0] ) ){
            $show_submenu=$args[0]['show_submenu'];
      }else
            $show_submenu=$args[0]->show_submenu;

      // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
      if ( ($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth >= $depth+1 ) && isset( $children_elements[$id]) && $element->title==$show_submenu) {

       foreach( $children_elements[ $id ] as $child ){

        if ( !isset($newlevel) ) {
         $newlevel = true;
         //start the child delimiter
         $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
         call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
        }
        $this->display_element( $child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output );
       }
       unset( $children_elements[ $id ] );
      }

      if ( isset($newlevel) && $newlevel ){
       //end the child delimiter
       $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $depth), $args);
       call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
      }

      if ($displaythiselement) {
              //end this element
              $cb_args = array_merge( array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
              call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);
      }
     }
    }
```

#### Display a submenu titled "About" from the "Main" menu (capitalization matters):

```
[menu menu='Main' show_submenu='About']
```

#### Display the full "Main" menu:

```
[menu menu='Main']
```

For further reading/reference see [this wordpress question](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_nav_menu-list-only-2nd-level-separate-submenu/page/2).

Answer (score -2):

I am surprised that Wordpress doesn't have this option built into the wp_nav_menu function. It has always been a struggle to implement secondary or split menus in Wordpress. After trying a number of different solutions to accomplish this goal I finally decided to make my own plugin that lets you choose the start depth for your menu. So you can just set the start depth to '1' for a secondary menu.

you use the plugin like this:

```
wp_nav_plus(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'start_depth' => 1));
```

The plugin is available on my site here for anyone interested: https://mattkeys.me/products/wp-nav-plus/

Comment: I'm a huge fan of plugin development and appreciate the effort you've obviously taken in extending the Wordpress framework. However, your "answer" does not contribute to this thread and is unhelpful to anyone but yourself.

Comment: Yea that is fair. I wrote this comment a while back now, before I really understood stackoverflow.

It is worth mentioning that the plugin I wrote about back then is open source if anyone wants to tear through the code to understand how it works or repurpose it for their needs. The code is more complex than I think I can summarize into an 'answer' to this question per stackoverflow standards though. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-nav-plus/