# How to Query Grandchildren and there sub children in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've been researching for a query that would display ul list of grandchildren pages and within each a another ul of the children pages. I think it would be going 3 & 4 levels deep? What I have right now as far as pages are:

Parent

- Child 1

--Grandchild 1

---Grandchild 1 child 1

--Grandchild 2

---Grandchild 2 child 1

- Child 2

--Grandchild 1

---Grandchild 1 child 1

--Grandchild 2

---Grandchild 2 child 1

- Child 3

--Grandchild 1

---Grandchild 1 child 1

--Grandchild 2

---Grandchild 2 child 1

Then basically when you are on a child, grandchild or granchild child it would display a menu list of all pages/links of the Child (but not the child itself in the menu).

I found how many things on parent and children, and even something with the grandchild, but nothing beyond the grandchild that would work? Any ideas or reference on how I can achieve this?

Comment: After trying the reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_Sub-Pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no luck after trying the references from: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_Sub-Pages

The closet thing I found from another resource in what I need to do is reliant on page ID:

```
<?php 
$parent = 64;
$args=array(
 'child_of' => $parent
);
$pages = get_pages($args);  
if ($pages) {
  $pageids = array();
  foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $pageids[]= $page->ID;
}
wp_list_pages($args);
}
?>
```

Though it will work, I am using templates that may be used throughout different pages. So if a grandchild or one of it's children is the page shown I need to show the whole list of the grandchild's parent (or in reality child 1, child 2 or child 3).

After many attempts I finally figured it out. I did go back and decided to make nav menus and by using if statements like this where I want the nav menu to appear.

```
<?php
   if ( is_page( 'child-1' ) || in_array( 3, get_post_ancestors($post->ID) ) ) {    
     menu2_nav();
   } elseif ( is_page( 'child-2' ) || in_array( 4, get_post_ancestors($post->ID) ) ) {  
     menu3_nav();
   } else { 
   }    
 ?>
```

So no matter if child 1 or child 2 uses the same template, example template-green, the correct nav menu will appear depending on the parent page listed. Also, if you're on a child page, or sub pages within that child no matter how deep the selected nav menu would show. The same code would be used on multiple templates such as template-blue, template-red, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways to do this:

First the simplest, just hide the top menu with CSS, display only the ones that are selected.

A bit of code I had luck with myself http://www.ordinarycoder.com/wordpress-wp_nav_menu-show-a-submenu-only/

And there's a duplicate question if you can find anything of use here: [WordPress wp_nav_menu specific sub menu only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355141/wordpress-wp-nav-menu-specific-sub-menu-only)

Comment: Thanks MarZab. I'm looking at what you sent and into a couple of other things that I'm trying out. I'll post something when I either get what I am trying to accomplish or either pretty close. For the most part though I'm not interested in using the nav menu, but more like wp list pages.